# Do consul possess an upper limit on number of consul watches?

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I am creating 200 watcher and i am getting EOF error repeatedly while Querying any consul CLI commands and then disconnection takes place. on consul logs i am seeing “too many files open” error while getting my consul up itself.

for ~150 entries I’m good to keep a watch and provide update on an HTTP endpoint.

**Setup** : 3 node consul agents in server mode were running. configuration file tries to register 200 Key watchers on KVs when one consul agent boots up.

I am doubting that this it is hitting open FD limit.

output of details are here :

1. **ulimit Output**

[rajkumar]# `ulimit -a`

- core file size (blocks, -c) 0
- data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
- scheduling priority (-e) 0
- file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
- pending signals (-i) 31186
- max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64
- max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
- open files (-n) 16384
- pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
- POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
- real-time priority (-r) 0
- stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
- cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
- max user processes (-u) 31186
- virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
- file locks (-x) unlimited

2. **for `lsof` on consul grep gives these results**

- *before running an agent*

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | grep ‘ESTABLISHED’ | wc -l`

0

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | wc -l`

603

- *with 150 watches these results are:*

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | grep ‘ESTABLISHED’ | wc -l`

3750

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | wc -l`

4563

- *with 500 watches running*

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | grep ‘ESTABLISHED’ | wc -l`

4040

[rajkumar]# `lsof | grep ‘consul’ | wc -l`

4881

3. **consul put response when the system stops responding**

[rajkumar]# `consul kv put new one`
Error! Failed writing data: Put http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/new: EOF

4. **consul members**

[rajkumar]# `consul members`

Error retrieving members: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/members?segment=_all: EOF

5. **consul get command error**

[rajkumar]# `consul kv get key14`

Error querying Consul agent: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/key14: read tcp 127.0.0.1:55574->127.0.0.1:8500: read: connection reset by peer

6. **consul agent process logs after boot up. I have created 500 watches in the config file.**

[image: Console]